# Rails: How to use minimised versions of css and js files in production and full versions in development?

Tags: javascript, css, ruby-on-rails

For example, I would like to develop with bootstrap.css but use bootstrap.min.css in production. Same for JS: jquery.js in development and jquery.min.js in production.

Ok, I must specify that the question is for Rails 3.0. From 3.1, you can indeed use the asset pipeline.

Comment: so what is your question?

Answer (score 0):

That's what the rails asset pipeline is for.

Add the unminified versions to your app and require them from application.css/application.js. In development the files will be served as is.

When config.assets.compress is true (ie in production by default) rails will minify the files for you

Comment: Sorry, I've forgot to mention it was for Rails 3.0